# Cartthrob Error after Update 4.2 and EE 5

Tags: cartthrob

Updated EE 3 to EE 5 and Cartthrob to 4.2.

Now we get this error message

```
    Warning
A non-numeric value encountered
user/addons/cartthrob/cartthrob/core/Cartthrob_product.php, line 151

Severity: E_WARNING`
```

Any ideas where to fix this?

EDIT:

After the fix from Harsh Barach we have this error message left

```
Warning
A non-numeric value encountered
user/addons/cartthrob/libraries/Cartthrob_variables.php, line 625

Severity: E_WARNING
```

Appreciate some help here.

Comment: I have modified my answer according to your new error. Please review it.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the Cartthrob_variables.php error, but in CartThrob 5.1.1.

Warning
A non-numeric value encountered
user/addons/cartthrob/libraries/Cartthrob_variables.php, line 484

Severity: E_WARNING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding type-casting to it. Try like below manner in the file from this path `system/user/addons/cartthrob/cartthrob/core/Cartthrob_product.php, line 151`.

Change `$price += $row['price'];` to `$price += (int)$row['price'];` in line 151. *I hope this will works for you.*

[image: Cartthrob Issue]

You need to add type-casting here like this way `$taxed_price = (int)$price * (1 + ee()->api_cartthrob_tax_plugins->tax_rate());` in line 625. *I hope this will also works for you*

[image: Cartthrob Issue 2]

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. This removed this error message. Now we have another one. Updated my entry.

Comment: @WernerGusset I have modified my answer according to your requirement. Please check it.

Comment: Yes, that error is gone too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I might add this note from Cartthrob support:for others: "As a side note, you do not want Line 151 to be `$price += (int)$row['price'];` because that will round your option price. Instead, you want to use `$price += (float)$row['price'];` which will allow it to be a floating point number with decimals." Version 4.3 should have this in place.

Comment: @WernerGusset That's great idea. Cartthrob should take care of these small issues. This is very nice idea to contribute to community.